# Chrome extension that clicks a button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I have a page with a button and I'm creating a chrome extension to click on it but it doesn't work:

```
<input type="submit" name="commit" value="add to basket" class="button"/>
```

This is my manifest.json

```
{
    "description": "Click",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "click-product-addtocart-button",
    "version": "0.1",

    "permissions": [
        "activeTab"
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": [
            "background.js"
        ]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "32": "/images/icons/16.png"
        },
        "default_title": "Click product"
    }
}
```

and this is my background.js

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id, {
        code: "document.getElementByName('commit')[0].click();"
    });
});
```

I click on the app but nothing happens. I have tried several things but that seems not to work

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: You may have to specifically check your extension console in `chrome://inspect#extensions`.

Comment: it says Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: That error doesn't make sense but you are using `getElementByName` (singular) instead of `getElementsByName` (plural). It's the latter.

Comment: @ShengSlogar i have tried even $('input[name="commit"]').click(); but nothing happen and it gaves the same error

Comment: Have you tried running that code straight on the webpage? Almost sounds like you have a syntax error in your markup, not in the extension itself. Would be useful to see this in a Codepen.

Comment: yes of course i have , but still doesn't work

Comment: Okay, then that's where you should be focusing your time. Get the function to work directly on the webpage first. Again, if you'd like to throw this into a JSFiddle or Codepen I'd be more than happy to help you debug further.

Comment: @ShengSlogar Ok if i go on the webpage and open the chrome console and put $('input[name="commit"]').click(); that works perfectly , but if i click the app it doesn't nothing , so i suppose there something wrong in the app

Comment: That's a great start. Note that you won't be able to use the `$` selector inside your app unless you're loading up jQuery. You'll want to stick to native DOM -- i.e. document.* selectors. I'm going to have to see screenshots or the entire project to give you more suggestions.

Comment: the entire project it the one i have uploaded in my post ahah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your manifest must request permission to access the current page by URL as well as just the current tab. Update your permissions to the following:

```
"permissions": [
     "activeTab",
     "*://*/*"
],
```

This will allow the extension to access any page. I would also recommend changing `name` to `id`. This will prevent any confusion in the future. You would do this as follows:

```
<input type="submit" id="commit" value="add to basket" class="button">
```

Then for background.js:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        code: "document.getElementById('commit').click();"
    });
});
```

You'll notice I also removed the specificity of the tab that you had in your question. This is not necessary.

Comment: ok so now it's    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
          "*://*/*"
    ], but still nto works

Comment: <script>
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(tab.id,{
        code: "$('input[name="commit"]').click();"
    });
});  it says unexpected token and highlight this part $('input[name="commit"]').click();"

Comment: @Marià you need to make sure you're very precise. Make sure the permission is "\*://*/*"

Comment: this is my manifest : https://i.gyazo.com/356cdfaf890769e8aea67fbbc4349ba9.png but still doesn0t work

Comment: and i can't edit the butto it doesn't have an id its' a third-part website